# creating a two column row

Tags: android, android-layout

I am having difficulty creating a two column row.  My requirements are that the first columns should take up 80% of the space, the second column 20%.

The first column text can be very long in which case it should wrap around but stay within 80% of the space.  The second column is easier, its always going to remain short and will not require wrapping.  But I want this second column to always be aligned vertically in the center to no matter how many times the first column wraps around.

How can I do this?

Here is what I have so far.  I need to improve this so the second column text is aligned vertically at the top, and the second column is aligned horizontally to the right

```
LinearLayout m_panel = new LinearLayout (this);
m_panel.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
m_panel.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

LinearLayout row_panel = new LinearLayout (m_panel.getContext());                           
row_panel.setWeightSum(1.0f);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new    LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.setMargins(2,8,1,8);
row_panel.setLayoutParams(lp);
row_panel.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);


TextView subjectName = new TextView(middlePanel.getContext());
subjectName.setLayoutParams(new     LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 0.2f));
subjectName.setText(someText);                              
row_panel.addView(subjectName);

TextView size = new TextView(middlePanel.getContext());     
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 0.8f);
size.setLayoutParams(lp2);

size.setText(sometext);

row_panel.addView(size);
```

Comment: think I figured it out first part, center vertically add this: size.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);

Comment: ok the full answer is size.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.RIGHT);

Comment: Well done. The question is, however, why are you creating this view dynamically using Java? It's clearly meant to be a definitive layout so why don't you do it with an XML layout file? ;-)

Comment: I do not know how many rows I need to render (or the data) until runtime.  Is this a good approach?  Or should I create a layout xml containing one row and then somehow duplicate it in the code?

Comment: If you don't know how many rows you need then it sounds like a good use for a `ListView` which dynamically manages things. If a `ListView` isn't an option (for some reason) you can still create an XML layout file for that layout and use `LayotInflater` to create as many instances as you need. It would make your code a lot tidier and potentially more robust.